# Inverted Text on Internet Explorer 10 Under VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I'm having some intermittent problems with the text changing colour on IE10 running on Win8 under VirtualBox 4.1.12 on my Ubuntu 12.04 Machine.

[image: Windows 8 IE9 Problem]

Is this a problem with VirtualBox or IE10? I'd be interested to find out the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off hardware acceleration for IE10. Open Internet Explorer, go to Tools → Options → Advanced, and uncheck "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering". Save and restart IE10.

Comment: Cheers - that seems to have done the trick. Honestly I'm a bit surprised that this was the default.